# Sanity.io - How to add locations in URL slug?

Tags: javascript, sanity

I have a location schema and a main schema. 'location' has multiple field and I want to choose one of those fields and add it into the URL of the main schema. Is this possible?

```
{
  name: 'location',
  type: 'object',
  fields: [
    {
      title: 'Locate',
      name: 'locate',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{ type: 'location' }]
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'slug',
  title: 'URL Slug',
  type: 'slug',
  options: {
    source: function (doc) {
      const fullNameSlug = doc.fullName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-').slice(0, 200);
      const locationSlug = doc.location && doc.location.locate
        ? `${doc.location.locate.city}-${doc.location.locate.state}`.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-').slice(0, 200)
        : '';
      // Combine the fullNameSlug and locationSlug to generate the final slug
      return `${fullNameSlug}-${locationSlug}`;
    },
    maxLength: 400, // Specify the maximum length of the slug if desired
  }
},
```

This is the snip of code I have although the URL slug shows main-page-undefined-undefined.